# Rails active model serializer - attribute alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, active-model-serializers

I'm integrating an Angular 2 application with Rails 5.1 API back-end.

I have a `Comment` model with `message` and `date` attributes in my Angular model. However in my Rails model for `Comment`, along with `message` attribute I have `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes automatically provided by `ActiveRecord::Migration` via `t.timestamps`.

I'm using `ActiveModel::Serializer` to have finer control on API reponses and in my `comment_serializer` I want to include `date` in place of `created_at` in API responses for each comment in `GET /comments`, `GET /comments/:id` etc. so that the Angular model need not be changed - how do I go about this assuming this is the right approach ?

Also when I'm adding a comment from the Angular client I want the `date` attribute in `Comment` model to be mapped to `created_at` in the corresponding `Comment` model in Rails - how do I go about this ?

Answer (score 14):

I think you needed this line in your serializer?

```
attribute :created_at, key: :date
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. I want to include date in place of created_at in API responses for each comment

To achieve this you have to define custom attribute in Serializer. Like this

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :message, :date

  def date
    object.created_at
  end
end
```

> 2. I want the date attribute in Comment model to be mapped to created_at

To achieve this, you just need to manually update created_at field while creating comment. Something like this

```
class CommentController < ApplicationController
    def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.created_at = params[:comment][:date]

    if @comment.save
        render :something
    else
        render :something
    end

  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:message, :next_field, :etc)
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.